# Django filter exclude with in and case senstive

Tags: django

Doe anyone know how to both exclude using the __in and also make this case senstive (__iexact)

```
Event.objects.values_list('total',flat=True).exclude(total__in=self.summaries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Q objects to constuct a query like this:

```
Event.objects.values_list('total',flat=True).exclude(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(total__iexact=word) for word in self.summaries])))
```

This Will work  for you